# How to upload the both image and video to server in swift 3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3

I am uploading images by using this source code, but videos are not uploading successfully.Where I have to change the source code for uploading videos.Please help me. Here I am shared my source code.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject])

{

    //imagepicker.allowsEditing = false
    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] {

        print("image is:\(pickedImage)")



         imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.image = pickedImage as? UIImage

        hideLabel.isHidden = true

        if let imageURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as? NSURL {
            let result = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withALAssetURLs: [imageURL as URL], options: nil)


            let fileNameObj = result.lastObject?.value(forKey: "filename") as? String ?? "Unknown"
            UserDefaults.standard.set(fileNameObj, forKey: "key4")


            self.fileNameLabel.text = fileNameObj
            picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)


            print("filename is:\(fileNameObj)")

        }
    }


  //  let documentsDirectoryURL =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    if let videoUrl =  info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as? URL {


        strUrl = videoUrl.absoluteString

        last4 = strUrl.substring(from:strUrl.index(strUrl.endIndex, offsetBy: -10))


        self.fileNameLabel.text = last4

        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        print("videourl is:\(String(describing: strUrl))")
        print("last4 is:\(String(describing: last4))")

    }




}




func createBodyWithParameters(parameters: [String: String]?, filePathKey: String?, imageDataKey: NSData, boundary: String) -> NSData {
    //var body = Data();
    var body = Data()

    if parameters != nil {
        for (key, value) in parameters! {
            body.appendString(string: "--\(boundary)\r\n")
            body.appendString(string: "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n")
            body.appendString(string: "\(value)\r\n")
        }
    }


    let imgObj = fileNameLabel.text
    let videoObj = fileNameLabel.text

    let newImg = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "key4")


    if imgObj == newImg{


        //let newObj = "manu.jpg"
        //let manuObj = fileNameLabel.text
        body.appendString(string: "--\(boundary)\r\n")

        let mimetype = "image/jpg"

        //let defFileName = fileNameObj



        let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image!, 1)
        print("defFileName is :\(String(describing: imageData))")

        let fnamed = fileNameLabel.text
        print("fnamed is:\(fnamed!)")
        body.appendString(string: "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(filePathKey!)\"; filename=\"\(fnamed!)\"\r\n")

        print("njsc is:\( body.appendString(string: "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(filePathKey!)\"; filename=\"\(fnamed!)\"\r\n"))")

        body.appendString(string: "Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n")
        body.append(imageData!)
        body.appendString(string: "\r\n")
        body.appendString(string: "--\(boundary)--\r\n")


    }
    else {
        let kBoundary = "Boundary-\(UUID().uuidString)"
        let kStartTag = "--%@\r\n"
        let kEndTag = "\r\n"
        let kContent = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n"



        body.append(String(format: kStartTag, boundary).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
        body.append(String(format: "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", "file", last4!).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
        body.append("Content-Type: video/mp4\r\n\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
        body.appendString(string: strUrl)
        body.append(String(format: kEndTag).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)

        // close form
        body.append("--\(boundary)--\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    }
    return body as NSData
}
```

Please help me to solve this issue.I am new to iOS Swift. or Please send me any related links for uploading images and videos successfully

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])
    {
        print(info)
        if info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] as? String == "public.image"
        {
            if let imagedata = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage        {

                PostImageView = imagedata
                btnphoto.setImage(imagedata, for: .normal)

            }

            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else
        {
            if let url  = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as? URL
            {
                SelectUrl = url
                dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                play(url: SelectUrl!)

            }

        }
    }

    func play(url:URL)
    {
        let player = AVPlayer(url: url)
        let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
        playerViewController.player = player
        self.present(playerViewController, animated: true)
        {
            playerViewController.player!.play()
        }

        do {
            let asset = AVURLAsset(url: url , options: nil)
            let imgGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
            imgGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
            let cgImage = try imgGenerator.copyCGImage(at: CMTimeMake(0, 1), actualTime: nil)
            thumbnail = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)

           btnVideo.setImage(thumbnail, for: .normal)



        } catch let error {
            print("*** Error generating thumbnail: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }

    }
```

**In service Code**

```
 if self.thumbnail != nil
                        {

                            dicParameter.setObject(self.thumbnail!, forKey: "video_thumb" as NSCopying)


                            let fileData = Utilities.getDataFrom(url: self.SelectUrl)

                            if fileData != nil {
                                var fileParameter : [String : Any] = [:]
                                fileParameter[FileParameter.fileName] = "video.mov"
                                fileParameter[FileParameter.fileData] = fileData
                                fileParameter[FileParameter.fileKey] = "post_file"
                                dicParameter.setObject(fileParameter, forKey: "post_file" as NSCopying)
                            }


                        }
                        else
                        {

                            let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.PostImageView! )
                            if imageData==nil { print("image data is nil"); return }
                            dicParameter.setObject(self.PostImageView, forKey: "post_file" as NSCopying)

                        }
```